# Does jQuery Lazy Loading have any real performance gains?

Tags: plugins, jquery, javascript, performance

[jQuery Lazy Loader](https://plugins.jquery.com/lazyload/) does the opposite of preloading images - it delays loading images until they are visible in the browser. This claims to make sites feel "snappier", and images elegantly fade in as the user scrolls down the page.

Mashable was known for using this technique (although I just checked and it appears they are no longer doing so).

Are there any realistic performance gains from using jQuery lazy loader, or does it just make the user *perceive* that the website is loading faster?

Comment: Voting to close as off topic. While this is a great question, it is not a WordPress question.

Comment: Sorry, I should specify that my application is for WordPress with this plugin: https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-image-lazy-loading/

Comment: Doesn't matter. This is a jQuery related question. It applies just as much to Joomla, Drupal, static HTML, Sharepoint, or any other kind of site as it does to WordPress. It is in no way specifically about WordPress and only happens to be related to WordPress because one possible use case involves WordPress.

Comment: Don't get me wrong; this is a great question. But it does not belong here.

Comment: I think you have your answer on the [official plugin site](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) in the big red box :)

Comment: @John: Where should this question be migrated to? Pro Webmasters? Or just Stack Overflow? I guess a mod will have to do the migration? But it's indeed an interesting question - I hope it results in less use of this annoying script :-)

Comment: @Jan: My guess is Stack Overflow. There are 20 questions tagged 'jQuery' on Pro Webmasters, but 65k on Stack Overflow. Might get a faster response on SO. If it belongs on PW, it'll get bounced there pretty quickly.

Comment: If you really want your images to load fast, then compress them, offer multiple sizes, and never use jQuery. jQuery = bad performance & slow page loads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends entirely on what *you mean* by "performance" and how lazy loading is used.

If you are just using lazy loading to load the same images you would otherwise load, then the same amount of bits are flowing across the stream, but indeed the packaging and IO costs more so from a 'server to client' perspective, it actually costs in 'performance'. It will do that to benefit the *user* who may indeed start consuming a portion of the content sooner than otherwise and so the *user perception* is improved, and that too is an element of "performance".

If you are using lazy loading to discriminate what data or images are being downloaded so that you can only bring that which the consumer wants, then you are getting real performance bonuses all around for not streaming undesired content.

How much of an "improvement"? Is it "worth it"? Well that is very subjective and *your mileage may vary*.

Answer (score 1):

I can describe my experience with lazy loading, which has suited my needs to hide hundreds of images until they are scrolled to.

When there where only 5 or so images off screen, the lazy loading will not be doing anything so no gain there. But the more images added to a single page with normal loading, I could really see my cheap tablet chugging away trying to load that much content along with rendering what was on screen. With lazy loading on, my tablet still took its time loading what was on screen, but when that was finished it was no longer stuttering tyring to load anything. So with just lazy loading the experience has improved for me, the user.

I have been using [lazySizes](https://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/), and one decision you will need to make is whether to commit to what it requires. All of my `<img>` use the `data-src` attribute rather than `src` making it reliant on the user having javascript enabled. If that is not an option for you I'm sure there are fallback options, I am just not aware of them.